# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') - NextJS

Tags: next.js

I was doing some changes in my index.js (nothing split related that I know) file in my NextJS app and after npm run dev, I got the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Call Stack
../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.5.1/node_modules/undici/lib/core/request.js
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (17232:45)
__require
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (16:50)
../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.5.1/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (18044:19)
__require
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (16:50)
../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.5.1/node_modules/undici/lib/pool.js
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (19367:18)
__require
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (16:50)
../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.5.1/node_modules/undici/lib/agent.js
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (19476:16)
__require
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (16:50)
src/polyfills/undici.js
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (19607:17)
__require
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (16:50)
addPrimitives
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (21753:18)
eval
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js (21855:19)
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/primitives/index.js
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (14475:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (661:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (316:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-web-streams.js (2:42)
./node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-web-streams.js
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (15152:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (661:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (316:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (47:5)
./node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (15207:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (661:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (316:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js (8:81)
./pages/index.js
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (14584:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (661:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/buksna/next/core/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (316:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js (5:16)
eval
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js (211:24)
```

Any help is appreciated. I am stuck here for a while now, not able to find a solution.

As stated, I haven't changed/added anything related to slice while committing the changes :)

EDIT => Here is my index.js file:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { renderToHTML } from 'next/dist/server/render';
import Header from '../components/Header';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
example: {
  color: 'red',
}
}));

function Home({posts}) {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
    <Header />
    {console.log(posts)}
    <div className={classes.example}>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <p>{post.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {

  const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props:{
      posts
    }
  };
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide more info, code, or repository. It could be a problem with the page name or something similar.

Just to be safe I would try to delete `.next` repository to clear cache and/or reinstall next library.

---------- EDIT ---------

try to remove this unused line `import { renderToHTML } from 'next/dist/server/render'` sometimes it breaks render because you are importing something for serverSide

Then try to comment on different parts of code to see which part do that.

Comment: In my case the error was happening because of unused imports. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `.split()` undefined value.
Find the line where vercel triggers you error and replace `value.next_value.split()` to `value?.next_value.split()`

**Why do you have this error appear during the build and not local?**

1. Because .split() code runs before your data loads.
2. Because your data load returns undefined or with errors.